# My webpack compiled successfully but server not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, server, webpack-dev-server

i'm setting up a React Webpack from scratch, webpack-dev-server is running normally, but the page is not load. I don't know which part is wrong.  Please help if you know how to fix it. appreciate.

error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Please help.

```css
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "webpack serve --mode development"
  },
```

```html
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    filename:'index.bundle.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    port:3010,
    static: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test:/\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude:/node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use:[
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you setting it up from scratch? Ultimately I think it's going to depend on how you've got your project structured. What the error is saying is that it can't find one of the files it needs. Double check that your file paths are correct.

Comment: project requirement is set up from scratch